# Python Firebase authentication

Tags: python, firebase

So I am trying to obtain some data from Firebase, which ofcourse has some rules/security constraints defined. I can authenticate my user from the **Login & Auth** tab, and I'd like to get data from firebase, however my user is still not authenticated.

`user = ref.authenticate(email, password)` , which returns the following for `user`

```
{
   u'token':{some long token here}',
   u'user':{
      u'uid':u'ef44b781-8842-4f28-abf0-2ac9aa0b2bea',
      u'provider':u'password',
      u'email':u'user@email.com',
      u'isTemporaryPassword':False,
      u'sessionKey':u'{session key here}}',
      u'md5_hash':u'{md5_hash here}}',
      u'id':u'ef44b781-8842-4f28-abf0-2ac9aa0b2bea'
   }
}
```

Now that I know the user is authenticated (otherwise it returns something along the lines of an error, I would like to do a simple GET `conversations = firebase.get(FIREBASE_NAME + '/conversations/' + me)`, where 'me' is the `user['user']['uid']`

I have the following structure for `conversations`:

`conversations/my-uid/other-uid/{data}`

I would think my user is authenticated, still it returns a PermissionDenied

**EDIT**
Solved this by using a different library you can find [here](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase). The initial library I used did not support authentication, while this one does. The way it was solved, was by implementing some functions from the other one and sending my token as follow: 
`FIREBASE.child('/messages/').get(token=token)`

Comment: I'd first try setting `".read": auth != null` at the top level of your security rules. If the read then succeeds, you know the problem is caused by your rules. If the read still fails, your user apparently is *not* authenticated after all. Note that in that cause it would help to know what library you are using to access Firebase.

Comment: It seemed to be a issue with the library indeed. I went and implemented some features from a different libraries, that did support the authenticated requests

Comment: Good to hear. Any way that you can write that into an answer about what library you used (both the initial one that didn't work and the new one that did)? That way others might benefit from your experience in the future.

Comment: Edited the initial post :-)

Comment: Thanks for that. It's better to provide the same information as an answer. That way you can accept your own answer and the SO system will recognize it as being solved.

Comment: Ha, did not know! Will do that ofcourse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by using a different library you can find [here](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase). The initial library I used did not support authentication, while this one does. The way it was solved, was by implementing some functions from the other one and authenticate as follows:

```
def auth_with_password(self, email, password):
    request_ref = 'https://auth.firebase.com/auth/firebase?firebase={0}&email={1}&password={2}'.\
        format(self.fire_base_name, email, password)
    request_object = self.requests.get(request_ref)
    return request_object.json()
```

Then to make an authorized call, do this

```
user = auth_with_password(email, password)
token = user['user']['token']
FIREBASE.child('/messages/').get(token=token)
```

Make sure your token is correct. The library supports this, but otherwise I would suggest that you use [Firebase token generator for Python](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-token-generator-python)

Comment: Wow! Plain password in the URL?!

Answer (score 2):

You should not send passwords in the URL, you can do this way:

```
__FIREBASE_USER_VERIFY_SERVICE = "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword"
__FIREBASE_API_KEY = __your_api_key_here__

def user_login(email, passwd):
    url = "%s?key=%s" % (__FIREBASE_USER_VERIFY_SERVICE, __FIREBASE_API_KEY)
    data = {"email": email,
            "password": passwd,
            "returnSecureToken": True}
    result = requests.post(url, json=data)
    is_login_successful = result.ok
    json_result = result.json()
    return json_result    # authToken=> json_result['idToken']
```

If successful, it will result like:

```
{
    "displayName": "",
    "email": "your_users_email@example.com",
    "expiresIn": "3600",
    "idToken": "abc123...",
    "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyPasswordResponse",
    "localId": "UWQ...x2",
    "refreshToken": "def098...",
    "registered": true
}
```

If fails (wrong password etc) :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "message": "INVALID_PASSWORD",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ],
    "message": "INVALID_PASSWORD"
  }
}
```

or may be

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "message": "MISSING_PASSWORD",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ],
    "message": "MISSING_PASSWORD"
  }
}
```